# Как получить список аккаунтов (учетных записей), используя к примеру AccountManager?

Tags: java, android, account

Для получения списка аккаунтов на устройстве Android 6.0 использую:

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
    System.out.println("Всего аккаунтов: " + accounts.length);
```

Но, массив "accounts" всегда нулевой длинны.

Разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

имеется!

Прошу подсказать решение проблемки.

Comment: В рантайме разрешения запрашиваете?

Comment: woesss, во время исполнения разрешения не запрашиваю. Я с этим не сталкивался.

Comment: Вопрос снят. Надо в райнтайме запрашивать! После запроса стало не ноль. Кто эту ерунду придумал?!